# Web application development in remote desktop vs. local desktop

Tags: helper

Which one is better -  developing application in remotely accessed machine or local machine? 
I'm working in IT department of health care institute, we using third party software, now started to development in our department itself with existing database, then the third party company demanded us to remotely access their machine for development purpose.

Comment: You have received an answer from a community member, but the question should be closed as off-topic. Pending edits should be discarded.

Comment: How fast your network is and how low the ping between your shop and the third party company also matters a lot.  At my last company we had developers work over RDP and it was fine, but we had a fast connection.

Answer (score 3):

This will get closed as off topic - but before it does....

Development will be faster and easier on a local machine and under your control.

The customer data/code/etc will be safer and more secure on a remote machine.

At the end of the day if the third party are paying you to develop remotely then warn them that it will extend development timescales and they will be billed accordingly and if they still want it go with it.

Sometimes you have to sacrifice efficiency to keep the customer happy.